# Implementing Sticky Kit on WordPress

Tags: sidebar

Can anybody tell me with how to implement [Sticky Kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) on my WordPress [hasbee](http://hasbee.com)?

Answer (score 2):

To include in the right way in your theme, you need to enqueue jQuery.sticky-kit.js with wp_enqueue_scripts action.

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_sticky_kit');

 function enqueue_sticky_kit(){
       wp_enqueue_script('sticky-kit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri .'/js/jQuery.sticky-kit.js', array('jquery') );
 }
```

Then in order to use it you'll need to add a small a little js

```
  $("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent();
  // or
  $("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent(options);
```

That can be done with `wp_head` action,

```
  add_action('wp_head', 'mycustom_sticky');

   function mycustom_sticky(){
          // Do what you need
        ?><script type="text/JavaScript">
                  $("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent();
            </script><?php
   }
```

Have a look to the documentation about jQuery noConflict to not affect other jQuery scripts.

Some jQuery code must be embed like this
      `jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
    [ your code goes here ]
} );`

Comment: I think there's something wrong with

Comment: <code>add_action('wp_head', 'mycustom-sticky'); function mycustom-sticky(){ // Do what you need ?><script type="text/JavaScript"> $("#sticky_item").stick_in_parent(); <\script><?php }


 </code> my site is crash, please fix this code

Comment: Something went wrong, this code can not break your site. Where did you put the code ? Verify open and closing php tag.

Comment: I just copied your code pasted on my functions.php, any idea?

Comment: Ok, you say it crash the site, what's the error ? White screen ?  did you adjust the path of the js file ?

Comment: You wrote ?> And <?php is that right code? Sorry for my grammar

Comment: Yes, because you add some 'html' in the head, so you close php with ?> And reopen it to finish the function after with <?php

Comment: Those made my site unable to handle that request.

Comment: How did you manage to make it work? I am also getting a white screen after i paste the mycustom-sticky code in functions.php.

Comment: Because of the "-" in the function name replace it with an underscore.... I correct it now

Comment: The jquery kit file and the function are both loaded. But i still can't get it to work. Do i need to change the jQuery.sticky-kit.js file to solve this?

Comment: You also need to enqueue jQuery library before the sticky-kit to make it work.

Comment: Isn't that a basic feature of WordPress? I can see a  jquery file being linked just before sticky-kit.

Comment: I can't tell more about this library. Have a look on the browser console to see if there is no errors